# running mysql_query multiple time in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to retrive the id`s of some produs based on their sdk.. but if there is 2 or multiple products, it returns me just the first id...

can anybody help me ?

Thanks a lot

This is the code that i used...(i`m new to php )

```
<?
     foreach(array_keys($nume_individual) as $n){

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE cod_produs = '$cod_produs_individual[$n]' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                $id_s[$n]=$row["id"];

        }


    echo (
        "<tr>
        <td>".$id_s[$n]."</td>  /* this is not working well (running just once) */
            <td>".$nume_individual[$n]."</td> 
        <td>".$cod_produs_individual[$n]."</td>
        <td>".$numar_individual[$n]."</td>
        <td>".$bucati_individual[$n]."</td>
        <td>".$pret_individual[$n]."</td>



        </tr>

        ");

        };?>
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: The `LIMIT 1` is pretty certain to return just one row.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: You should also avoid queries inside tight loops as they are prone to the N+1 Problem.

Comment: I need a macro to insert *use PDO* blurb...

Comment: not the limit 1 it`s the problem.... that specify that 1 row / loop... .. removed the limit 1... and there is the same problem
I`m new to php and coding and it`s not easy :).. i`m facing this problem for 2 hours... i was searching entire google for this

Comment: how i avoid using quires in the loop in this situation? and the $n it`s changing in the forach loop... just in the query it`s not

Comment: @user1483138 How do you know the value of $n is not changing in the query? The way you have your loop set up, you are referencing all your array values with $n as a key. In this way, your SQL query and result don't do anything to the printed output. If you comment out the those few lines, you'll see what I mean. Since you are making a DB call, and extracting the ID, I'm assuming you want to actually use the ID from the DB, not the value of $n as a key for getting the values of your arrays.

Comment: i know that $n its changing because $n it`s the position of the elements in the array, .. all those variables are arrays.. and i`m retrieving all the values even if there are 3-4 products in the arrays... (all it`s working fine except the mysql_query.. who it`s running just for the first position of the array...

Comment: @PeeHaa, I appreciate the feedback. A bit critical. But I get the gist.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary It is a bit critical, but it is honest. And in no way meant as a personal attack, but I'm sure you got that. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Here is the code , maybe it will be usefull for someone :)

```
<? 
$cod_produs_individual2 = array_pop($cod_produs_individual) ;
$csv =implode(',', $cod_produs_individual); 
$csv2 = "'" . join("', '", $cod_produs_individual) . "'"; 
$csv3= $string = rtrim($csv2, ',');

$query2 = sprintf("SELECT * 
                    FROM products 
                   WHERE cod_produs IN (%s)",
                  $csv3); 

$results2 = mysql_query($query2);
$randuri = mysql_num_rows($results2);

$a = array();

if ($randuri >0) { while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results2)){ 

    array_push ($a, $row["id"]);

        }
}
print_r ($a);

foreach(array_keys($nume_individual) as $n){

    echo (
    "<tr>
    <td>".$a[$n]."</td>
    <td>".$nume_individual[$n]."</td>
    <td>".$cod_produs_individual[$n]."</td>
    <td>".$numar_individual[$n]."</td>
    <td>".$bucati_individual[$n]."</td>
    <td>".$pret_individual[$n]."</td>



    </tr>

    ");



    };?>
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you have set the limit 1 so that it will only return just one row

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                     FROM products 
                      WHERE cod_produs = '$cod_produs_individual[$n]' 
                      LIMIT 1 // this is the reason you getting only one row 
                      ");
```

second you using the echo outside of the while loop use this inside of while loopp

Comment: that is limit 1 / loop... that`s what i want.. 1 row / loop... anyway.. i removed it because i don`t have 2 identical rows in database.. and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Put your `echo` inside the while loop, and remove the `limit 1` from your query.

When you have a `limit 1` in your query, you are limiting the results to return only 1 row from the DB. Also, when you have the echo outside of your while loop, you will only be printing the last loaded row from the DB.

It also appears you're printing the values at the key of $n from certain arrays. I don't know what $n is, but you might want to try using the row's ID, since you are using the main foreach index.

```
foreach(array_keys($nume_individual) as $n){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE cod_produs = '$cod_produs_individual[$n]'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $id_s[$n]=$row["id"];
        echo (
            "<tr>
            <td>".$row["id"]."</td>  
            <td>".$nume_individual[$row["id"]]."</td>
            <td>".$cod_produs_individual[$row["id"]]."</td>
            <td>".$numar_individual[$row["id"]]."</td>
            <td>".$bucati_individual[$row["id"]]."</td>
            <td>".$pret_individual[$row["id"]]."</td>
            </tr>"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: if i write it like this, it`s running once.. even if in the array are 2 products.... if i let it how i write it... it works but it retrive only 1 id, and to the second products... the id space it`s empty..

Comment: I've edited my answer. Basically, you are using the $n key inside of your while loop, but you should be using the `$row["id"]` as the key value to reference everything. This is because as you said, it's possible to have an instance where there's one value in `$nume_individual` but have duplicate DB ids.

Comment: edited my question... only the first row it`s not working ...